# jQuery Accordion Cookie will not save state

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Accordion Menu will not save with Cookie the state. Can not find out what is wrong on my Code. Would be happy to get a clue. I am not a Coder and trying to learn and do it myself.

** EDIT **
I worked on my Code but still could not clear my Problem :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function (index, e) {
        var count = $(e).find('li').length;
        var content = '<span class="cnt">+</span>';

        $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
    });
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        var checkElement = $(this).next();


        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');

            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp(
                function () {
                    $(".cnt").text("+")
                }
            );

        }

        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');


            checkElement.slideDown('normal');

            $("#cssmenu ul ul:visible").slideDown(
                function () {
                    $(".cnt").text("-")
                }
            );

        }

        if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you update the setting of cookie as follows? $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).find('li').index(ui.newHeader[0]));  see if this works?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Updated by it does not keep the state of the menu

Comment: can you please add your html and JavaScript to jsfiddle and post the link?  I would like to look at the code...